# Is it possible to use a CO2 sensor to detect how many people are in a room?

Tags: smart-home, sensors, system-architecture

I have [MH-Z14 Carbon Dioxide sensor](https://www.winsen-sensor.com/products/ndir-co2-sensor/mh-z14.html) and have been using it to try and detect when a room may need some fresh air. But, I've also noticed that the sensor reading drastically increases when a human is present in a room and especially if close to the sensor itself.

I am wondering if anyone tried to use the current CO2 value in a room to detect an approximate number of people in a room and how possible and accurate could it be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@jsotola's comment (Something like: "Sounds like something machine learning could do") is probably the right answer, but I'll expand on it a little.

It's going to depend on at least the following factors:

- Size of the room
- Number of people
- Type of activity the people are doing
- Amount of ventilation the room has (windows/ac/...)
- Accuracy and response time of the sensor used
- Number and position of sensors

I have used data from a CO<sub>2</sub> sensor to roughly estimate room occupancy in the past for a single room, I didn't end up going down the machine learning route at the time, rather using things like the rate of change CO<sub>2</sub> to give an indicator (more people the quicker the value went up). But if I was doing it again I probably would start gathering data to use as training material.

It might also be worth fusing the data with another sensor, e.g. a relative humidity sensor as this is also likely to increase at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

It appears some research has been done on this already – [Sensing by Proxy: Occupancy Detection Based on Indoor CO<sub>2</sub> Concentration](http://bayen.eecs.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/journals/sensing_by_proxy.pdf) describes a model developed at the University of California, Berkeley to detect occupancy based on CO<sub>2</sub> concentration.

> We propose a link model that relates the proxy
>   measurements with unknown human emission rates based on a
>   data-driven model which consists of a coupled Partial Differential
>   Equation (PDE) – Ordinary Differential Equation (ODE) system.

Their model is apparently more accurate than other machine learning models they tested:

> The inference of the number of
>   occupants in the room based on CO2 measurements at the air
>   return and air supply vents by sensing by proxy outperforms a
>   range of machine learning algorithms, and achieves an overall
>   mean squared error of 0.6569 (fractional person), while the best
>   alternative by Bayes net is 1.2061 (fractional person).

Algorithm 1 (p. 3) in the paper may give some direction on how to implement a similar system to theirs, which seems to be surprisingly reliable given the simplistic nature of the CO<sub>2</sub> sensor.